# Can I get a medical after having had a seizure eight years ago?

Tags: faa-regulations, medical

In 2010 I had a seizure (as of this writing that would be 8 years ago.)

I was a CFI/Commercial Multi pilot, and the FAA took away my medical. I have never piloted since, though I've missed it tremendously.

At the time I was told that I could not obtain a medical again unless it was after 6 years being seizure free with 2 off medication. I have been off medication for 1 year and have had no problems.

I recently got a battery of tests (EKG, MRI, CAT Scan/CT Scan) etc and found no seizure activity.

Have the rules changed in nearly a decade for this? Should I see an AME or would it be a waste of time? I know there is a pilot shortage now, so I'm wondering if it has gotten more lenient.

Comment: What kind of flying do you want to do? CFI? ATP? The rules have not really changed for Class-1/Class-2 medicals, Class-3 went through an overhaul with BasicMed, but it wouldn't affect you unless you wanted to be a CFI.

Answer (score 4):

This is something [only an authorized AME](https://www.faa.gov/pilots/amelocator/) can answer for you and it there is no harm in talking to one or two of them. You can find a [little bit of info here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/app_process/exam_tech/item46/amd/nc/) and a copy of the [seizure questionnaire here](https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/media/AirmanSeizureQuestionnaire.pdf) but that appears to be something an AME would fill out so its contents are not really useful on its own.

> At the time I was told that I could not obtain a medical again unless
>   it was after 6 years being seizure free with 2 off medication. I have
>   been off medication for 1 year and have had no problems.

If you were explicitly told this when the FAA pulled your medical then you still have another year to go at which time you can reapply for a medical.

In terms of regulations **[§67.401 Special issuance of medical certificates](https://www.ecfr.gov/cgi-bin/text-idx?c=ecfr&sid=5c0d1766e37c2027601b6684dcd4e1bd&rgn=div8&view=text&node=14:2.0.1.1.5.5.1.1&idno=14)** allows the FAA to issue medical certificates to airmen who can demonstrate "a Statement of Demonstrated Ability (SODA)" which is at the discretion of the flight surgeon. In short the regulation reads, if you can show that you are fit to fly and we agree we can issue a medical as we see fit.

What has changed quite a bit is the big overhaul that included the [Basic Med requirements](https://www.faa.gov/documentLibrary/media/Advisory_Circular/AC_68-1A.pdf) which do include some notes on special issuance cases that you may be able to operate under.

For you it also depends on what kind of operations you want to do since you are a CFI/Commercial. If you just want to get back in the air it may be a bit easier to do that.

From what I can tell it looks like you can get it back but you will need to talk to an AME.

Answer (score 0):

Check your seizure from here : https://www.icao.int/publications/Documents/8984_cons_en.pdf

It will at least give you an idea about your situation. 
I guess that your seizure is caused by your heart (According to the scans they have asked). If it is neurological, situation changes completely.

Answer (score 0):

Seizures doesn't appear in the FAA list of special issuance conditions for Cat 1 so you may be out of luck.

https://www.faa.gov/about/office_org/headquarters_offices/avs/offices/aam/ame/guide/special_iss/all_classes/

But I would write to an AME anyway.  Nothing to lose.

In Canada the authorities seem to be somewhat more lenient on medical conditioins. Transport Canada has recently issued Cat 1s to a few airline pilots with Type 1 insulin dependent diabetes (albiet with tight restrictions and monitoring requirements).

Answer (score 0):

I’d suggest you talk that one over with an AME and we what they have to say.  It may be a lengthy process but it can be done.  I’d also suggest, if you can, make contact with John King of King Schools in San Diego.  He had his medical temporarily revoked but managed to get it reinstated after having a seizure.  He could also shed some light on the process you’ll face.